# What are the side-effects of disabling nested loops in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

A query of multiple joins spends a lot of time on nested loops. I disabled the nested loops and the query ran much faster. However, I have been told that nested loops might give me wrong results by skipping some tuples. Is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using debugging parameters like `enable_nestloop` should not change the results of a query. If it does that'd generally be a bug.

However, you should not use `enable_nestloop = off` or similar in production. It's a very big hammer, and while it might appear to fix your immediate problem, it'll create performance problems elsewhere. A nested loop is often the correct plan node for best performance in a part of a query, and forcing PostgreSQL to prefer other options might make queries significantly slower.

Instead, you should generally adjust the cost parameters like `random_page_cost` to encourge PostgreSQL to choose a plan that performs better on your hardware and workload. For more information see the tuning advice on the PostgreSQl wiki and in the main documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I already manipulated the random_page_cost. What if I disable nestloops only for that query? Postgresql already does that. I can only disable nestloops for the duration of that query.
Also if I had table with too many columns, would dividing it improve the performance?

Comment: If the planner is choosing a slower plan than the best possible, then either the cost parameters aren't correct for your system, the statistics don't reflect the actual data, or there's a planner bug/limitation preventing choice of the best plan. If you've conclusively eliminated the first two, then you could choose to force a join type. I don't do that myself, as I find that it becomes a problem later when the data has changed/grown because it prevents the planner from adapting to changes in the data.